# Removing substring out of string using sed

Tags: bash, sed, substring

I am trying to remove substring out of variable using sed like this:

```
PRINT_THIS="`echo "$fullpath" | sed 's/${rootpath}//' -`"
```

where

```
fullpath="/media/some path/dir/helloworld/src"
rootpath=/media/some path/dir
```

I want to echo just rest of the fullpath like this (i am using this on whole bunch of directories, so I need to store it in variables and do it automatically

```
echo "helloworld/src"
```

using variable it would be

```
echo "Directory: $PRINT_THIS"
```

Problem is, I can not get sed to remove the substring, what I am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You don't need `sed` for that, `bash` alone is enough:

```
$ fullpath="/media/some path/dir/helloworld/src"
$ rootpath="/media/some path/dir"
$ echo ${fullpath#${rootpath}}
/helloworld/src
$ echo ${fullpath#${rootpath}/}
helloworld/src
$ rootpath=unrelated
$ echo ${fullpath#${rootpath}/}
/media/some path/dir/helloworld/src
```

Check out the [String manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) documentation.

Comment: Thank you, its funny because i used string manipulation elsewhere in script but forgot about it

Comment: If you don't know if $rootpath ends with a slash, you can do: `shopt -s extglob; echo "${fullpath##$rootdir*(/)}"`

Comment: Unable to use it for my example,  I have `one="branch_name_something"` and `two = "branch_name_"`. I want to print only "something"" from $one. So, I tried  `echo ${#${two}one}` but it throws `-bash: ${#${two}one}: bad substitution`. Not sure what am I missing.

Comment: The syntax you're using is completely different from the one I used above.

Answer (score 13):

To use variables in sed, you must use it like this :

```
sed "s@$variable@@g" FILE
```

two things :

- I use double quotes (shell don't expand variables in single quotes)
- I use another separator that doesn't conflict with the slashes in your paths

Ex:

```
$ rootpath="/media/some path/dir"
$ fullpath="/media/some path/dir/helloworld/src"
$ echo "$fullpath"
/media/some path/dir/helloworld/src
$ echo "$fullpath" | sed "s@$rootpath@@"
/helloworld/src
```